# array of nested objects with json_agg and using count in nested aggregation

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

In my query, I need to return an array of nested objects from the database, in this format:

```
[
   {
      "folder_name": "a parent folder",
      "document_count": 4,
      "child_folders": [
         {
            "child_folder_name": "child folder 1",
            "document_count": 2
         },
         {
            "child_folder_name": "child folder 2",
            "document_count": 2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

The parent folder document count represents all documents in the parent folder.

The child folder document count represents all documents in the child folder.

Here's the query I have written:

```
select json_agg(req_folders) as request_folders_and_counts
from (
     select json_build_object(
        'id', dfr.folder_id,
        'folder_name', f.name,
        'document_count', count(d.*),
         'child_folders',
                case
                when cf.name is null then null
                else 
                 json_agg(json_build_object('child_folder_name', cf.name, 'document_count', count(d.*)))
                end
         ) req_folders
    from documents_folders_requests dfr
join folders f on dfr.folder_id = f.id
join documents d on dfr.document_id = d.id
left join folders cf on dfr.child_folder_id = cf.id
where dfr.request_id = 22814
group by dfr.folder_id, f.name, cf.name) t;
```

There are two problems with this query:

1. the child_folders array is not capturing all the child_folder_ids, it's only returning the first child_folder on the association.
2. The document count in the child_folder objects is not permitted, because it is a nested aggregation.

How do I solve for these two problems?

Edit: here's some more data to help make the relationships easier to follow. I'm excluding non-relevant columns for simplification.

```
Folder (also the model for the child_folder_id)

| id | name |

{ 1, "a parent folder" }

{ 2, "child folder 1 }

{ 3, "child folder 2" }
```

```
Document 
| id | request_id | title |

{ 11, 22814, "a great document.txt" }
{ 22, 22814, "another great document.pdf" }
etc ...
```

```
Request 
| id | 
{ 22814 }
```

```
DocumentsFoldersRequest
| id | folder_id | child_folder_id | document_id | request_id |

{ 100, 1, 2, 11, 22814 }
{ 101, 1, 3, 22, 22814 }
```

Comment: Please provide sample data to go along with your desired results.

Comment: @GMB like the db records themselves?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I think it would make your question easier to follow, rather than backtracking the data from the query and results.

Comment: @GMB I updated it - let me know if that's clarifying, or if I should format it differently, thanks